# jquery активный chekbox

Tags: jquery

есть чекбоксы установленные на фильтр, мне нужна проверка если отмечен хоть один чекбокс , то скрыть определенный блок. Я отмечаю чекбокс, нужный блок скрывается, но после того как я нажимаю в фильтре "найти" происходит перезагрузка страницы и скрытый блок снова отображается хотя чекбокс активный

```
var explode = function() {
$('.icr-label input, .podrob_body select').change(function(){
if(this.checked) {
$('.catalogtype1').hide();
}else {
$('.catalogtype1').show();
}
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то у вас блок будет скрываться только после срабатывания события "change".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
       $('.catalogtype1').hide(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: все работает, но после перезагрузки блок не исчезает, хотя флажок остался активным